# Connect camera TF tree and robot TF tree

Tags: ros, iai-kinect2, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm a newer of ROS.

I want to add the kinect camera to my Industrial robot working environment.

So, I follow [this tutorials](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/perception_pipeline/perception_pipeline_tutorial.html) to set up all of confirgure.

When I launch the moveit demo.laucnch file, it shows error messages below.

```
[ WARN] [1553832710.822016764]: No transform available between frame 'kinect2_rgb_optical_frame' and planning frame '/world' (Could not find a connection between 'world' and 'kinect2_rgb_optical_frame' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.) [ WARN] [1553832710.822063875]: No transform available between frame 'kinect2_link' and planning frame '/world' (Could not find a connection between 'world' and 'kinect2_link' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.) [ WARN] [1553832710.822099052]: No transform available between frame 'kinect2_ir_optical_frame' and planning frame '/world' (Could not find a connection between 'world' and 'kinect2_ir_optical_frame' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.)
```

And this is the situation of TF tress.

[image: image description]

Anyone can help me?

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319854/connect-camera-tf-tree-and-robot-tf-tree/) by [A_YIng](https://answers.ros.org/users/40085/a_ying/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2019-03-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your tf tree is looking for camera_link however your kinect broadcasting sensor msgs in kinect2_link frame. A simple way is that use a static transform publisher to link kinect2_link and camera_link, you could execute the following command line

```
rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 camera_link kinect2_link 10
```

check this for reference
http://wiki.ros.org/tf#static_transform_publisher

---

Originally posted by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) with karma: 710 on 2019-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3